# How to update via <p:ajax event="filter"?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am unable to update input text with the globalFilter data.

I can see the globalFilter value in the bean and I also check  with Firebug that I am using the correct id but still the play value is empty.

```
<p:dataTable id="osTable"       
                 var="object" 
                 value="#{bean.lazyModel}" 
                 selection="#{bean.selectedObject}" 
                 selectionMode="single"
                 rowKey="#{object.ID}"
                 paginator="true"
                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 rows="10"
                 widgetVar="tableWidgetVar">
        <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{bean.onFilter}" update="osTable:play"/>
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <p:outputPanel id="panel" style="float: left">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {tableWidgetVar.filter()}" style="width: 100px"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear Filter" ajax="true" action="#{bean.update}" onclick="document.getElementById('osTable:globalFilter').value = ''"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>  
            <h:inputText id="play" value="#{bean.filter}"/>
        </f:facet>
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `onFilter` is executed? try to update the id only, like this `update="play"` , also try this test , place some `h:inputText ` outside the table (in same `h:form`) and try to update it by using the same `<p:ajax event="filter"` , see if it works

Comment: the ajax is working only if the h:inputText is outside the table with update=":mainForm:play" ,any idea why ?

Comment: dunno , try to upgrade to latest pf and use the http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf , then you'll add `styleClass="some_class"` to your `h:inputText ` and use `update="@(.some_class)"` , this might work...

Comment: I don’t know how to make it work I try to play with it but still it’s not working if you could send me a working example it would be great

Comment: try this `<p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{bean.onFilter}" update="@(.play_class)"/>` and this `<h:inputText styleClass="play_class" value="#{bean.filter}"/>` (make sure you are using primefaces 3.3.1)